# How to model the relationship between two aggregate roots

Tags: java, jpa, domain-driven-design

I have one class named `Question` and another named `StudentDriver`. `StudentDriver` have a list of questions. Since both classes are aggregate roots they have their own repository.

When I am going to add a new question, should the `StudentDriver` class have a method named `addQuestion()?` And would I merge the studentdriver object through the studentdriver repository, or would I persist the question with the question repository? If I persist it with question repository then the list of questions belonging to a studentdriver would not contain the newly added question until I refresh it from the database.

I don't understand the connection between the two aggregate root objects and how I am going to model it correctly.

*I am using JPA.*

Comment: Why don't you implement what you need to implement based on the user interface needs, or on what the external API must provide? Are you aware that what you do in a transaction is not visible from other concurrent transactions anyway, and that every new transaction starts from scratch and loads everything from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have two options:

1) Two aggregate roots. Adding new question would look like this:

```
StudentDriver student = studentsRepository.findById(id);
Question question = someFactory.CreateForStudent(student);
questionsRepository.Persist(question);
```

And getting all questions for a student will be a responsibility of the questions repository:

```
IList<Question> studentQuestions = questionsRepository.findByStudent(student);
```

Essentially you have a persistent unidirectional relationship from question to student: Question-belongs-to-StudentDriver (many-to-one).

2) One aggregate root. StudentDriver is a root of the aggregate that contains list of questions. Adding new question would look like this:

```
StudentDriver student = studentsRepository.findById(id);
student.addNewQuestion("Should you stop on a red light?", "Yes");
studentsRepository.Persist(student);
```

To get all questions for a student you would use something like:

```
IList<Question> studentQuestions = student.GetAllQuestions();
```

The choice between two options depends on the information that is missing from the OP. Good way to identify aggregate root is to look at a lifecycle logic. Questions like

- Can Question exist without corresponding Student?
- Can Question be 'reassigned' from one Student to another?
- When you delete/archive Student, should all Questions also be deleted?

Comment: What if my StudentDriver has to have actual list of Question IDs (for some complex business logic that should not use repository)? (both being separate ARs)